# jQuery get values of 4th and greater number of checkboxes clicked using an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running an each loop to a form, to sum values based on user selections and get the final price of a product.
The hard part is that in specific checkbox groups I have further restrictions like: the group A will start adding to the price, after 4 and more checkboxes are clicked and only add the values of those clicked after the 3rd item.

Below is the function that I ve created and I am searching of a solution to my problem:

```
var quantity = 1;
var removedProductPrice = false; //User can pick a variation of the same product, so the price changes to that selected variation (flag)    
var product_price = parseFloat($("#product").val()); //Base product price
var totalProduct = product_price;

$(":input", "#productForm").each(function(){
    if(this.type == 'checkbox' || this.type == 'radio'){
        if(this.checked == true){

            priceProtocol = $(this).attr('rel').split('_');
            //priceProtocol[0]: 'variation/component/steady, priceProtocol[1]: number of choices

            switch(priceProtocol[0]){               
                case 'variation':
                    removedProductPrice = true;
                    totalProduct = Number(totalProduct)+Number(this.value);
                break;

                case 'component':                       
                    totalProduct = Number(totalProduct)+Number(this.value);                     
                break;          

                case 'steady':                      
                    //If the number of clicked checkboxes is greater than the limit, start adding to the price
                    if($("input[name='"+this.name+"']:checked").length > priceProtocol[1]){                         
                        totalProduct = Number(totalProduct)+Number(caller.val());
                    }
                break;  
            }

        }
    }else if(this.id == 'product_quantity'){ quantity  = this.value; }
});

//If a variation selected, change the price to that of the variation
if(removedProductPrice){ totalProduct = totalProduct-product_price; }

//Multiple by the selected quantity
totalProduct = Number(quantity)*totalProduct;

    //Preview the final price
$("#current_product_price").html(totalProduct.toFixed(2));  
 }
```

How can I achieve that described above?

Answer (score 0):

For only adding price after 4 or more checkboxes are selected you could use the [selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
if ($("#GroupAId option:selected").length > 4) {
...
}
```

For only adding items clicked after the 3rd item you may be able to use the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method. Only add items with an index > 2 (zero based)

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>

...

var listItem = document.getElementById('bar');
alert('Index: ' + $('li').index(listItem));
//We get back the zero-based position of the list item:
//Would alert - Index: 1
```

Hope that helps

Comment: RKumsher I already check if the conditions are ok to add the values: 

if($("input[name='"+this.name+"']:checked").length > priceProtocol[1])

The problem is how to add only those clicked after 3rd item (4th, 5th 6th etc).

Comment: How about on each check you add the checkbox to an ordered list and on each uncheck you remove the checkbox.  Then in you calculation, only account for checkboxes with index of 3 or greater.  Hopefully I'm understanding your question correctly

Comment: Yes but it could be more than 2 groups of checkboxes with the same characteristics in the form.

For example: from the first group summing up starts when user clicks the 4th checkbox item while from the second group starts when user clicks on the 2nd item.

Comment: Can you give me a code example using ordered list for each group? This function triggers on click event. Also the groups of checkboxes are created dynamically.